# Can anyone help a newbie group get started with P&P D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

My friends and I have been always being fascinated with D&D, and even better the community is great and really helpful.

Can you help us get started with D&D?  Since we've never played the Pen-and-Paper, our knowledge goes through PC games (Baldurs Gate 1,2 , NWN 1,2, Icewind Dale 1,2 etc...) so we know the basics of both AD&D and 3.0/3.5 edition.

**BUT** the thing that is bothering us and which is why we are asking you for our help is simple.

What edition to choose to play with ?

We have seen through web research guides for 4th edition and 5th, none for AD&D and 3.0/3.5. Our local game shop sells AD&D, 3.5 ,4th and 5th player handbooks and monster manual with dungeon masters guide.  We don't know if we should we go with the ones we are familiar with or with the new editions?

A lot of people say that 4th and 5th edition are newbie friendly, while 3.5 edition gives more 'freedom', any opinions on this ?

Seeing the difference between the P&P and video games is what made us to go out there and get started.

Thanks in advance, even if we don't get any answers, I just wish to say again that the community has so far been best for how far we've seen it.

Comment: Related: [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212)

Comment: Welcome! I think you'll find good arguments for any edition; that given a set of desired experiences we'd be able to recommend one that's "right" for those objectives; and that with zero experience it's impossible to know or articulate those desires. So I'll see if we can scope this from a different perspective: what are you afraid of going "wrong" if you pick "badly"?

Comment: (BTW, I believe this is likely to get closed in its current state: please don't be discouraged. [On Hold] is a status which will prevent poorly-aimed answers from coming in while we help you sort out what the *question* really is (and if there's a Stack-answerable nucleus in there). Once that's settled I'm sure the answers will fly in. (If it ends being the sort of question we're good at answering.))

Comment: Also, if you get to 20 rep on site, please come to [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), where we can advise in less formal manner. Starting with RPGs is a very broad issue and depends on a lot of personal preferences.

Comment: Possibly related: [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033)

Comment: I will suggest that if this question is to be saved, it would need to be phrased something like "here is my groups D&D experience, is X edition the best on to start with in transition from computer D&D to P&P D&D?"  That confines it to a given edition, avoids becoming a shopping list/game rec question around which potential "edition wars" could arise and thus disqualify the question.  This also would make for a yes or no answer, or a set of them.

Comment: Related questions on starting D&D include [5e material needed](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74664/what-resources-are-really-needed-to-start-5e), [can newbies start 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70431/is-starting-a-group-with-5-newbies-dm-included-possible), [how to use the starter set](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71290/how-to-use-the-dd-starter-set).   If similar questions on 4e are available those links would also be related.